# How to use jar file that calls jax-ws web service in android studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, jax-ws

I'm trying to use jar file that calls jax-ws web service on Android Studio,

I know the ksoap2 library with Android Studio, but I've client web service jar file to use it on Android Studio.

I'v tried this jar file on simple java project in eclipse (I've added the libraries) [axis.jar, commons-discovery-0.2.jar, commons-logging.jar, javamail-mailapi-1.4.jar, jaxrpc.jar, saaj.jar, wsdl4j.jar], and it's worked fine.

On Android Studio, I'v added the mentioned libraries with my jar file.

when I ran the app, I faced this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files
> copied in APK META-INF/ECLIPSE_.SF    File1:
>
> /home/user/Desktop/TestWebServiceCalling/app/libs/wsdl4j.jar      File2:
> /home/user/Desktop/TestWebServiceCalling/app/libs/commons-logging.jar

After I deleted the two library files (wsdl4j.jar, commons-logging.jar), I faced the following error:

> To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
> Itcurrently has approximately 989 MB. For faster builds, increase the
> maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB. To do
> this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project
> gradle.properties. For more information see
> https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
> Error:trouble processing "javax/xml/messaging/Endpoint.class":
> Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or
> javax.*) Error:when not building a core library. Error:This is often
> due to inadvertently including a core library file Error:in your
> application's project, when using an IDE (such as Error:Eclipse). If
> you are sure you're not intentionally defining a Error:core class,
> then this is the most likely explanation of what's Error:going on.
> Error:However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a
> core Error:namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for
> example, Error:from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will
> most Error:assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
> Error:compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
> Error:It is also often of questionable legality. Error:If you really
> intend to build a core library -- which is only Error:appropriate as
> part of creating a full virtual machine Error:distribution, as opposed
> to compiling an application -- then use Error:the "--core-library"
> option to suppress this error message. Error:If you go ahead and use
> "--core-library" but are in fact Error:building an application, then
> be forewarned that your application Error:will still fail to build or
> run, at some point. Please be Error:prepared for angry customers who
> find, for example, that your Error:application ceases to function once
> they upgrade their operating Error:system. You will be to blame for
> this problem. Error:If you are legitimately using some code that
> happens to be in a Error:core package, then the easiest safe
> alternative you have is to Error:repackage that code. That is, move
> the classes in question into Error:your own package namespace. This
> means that they will never be in Error:conflict with core system
> classes. JarJar is a tool that may help Error:you in this endeavor. If
> you find that you cannot do this, then Error:that is an indication
> that the path you are on will ultimately Error:lead to pain,
> suffering, grief, and lamentation. Error:1 error; aborting
> :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED Error:Execution failed for
> task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

Thank you in advanced